# how to optimize my existing code to solve google kickstart round b 2020

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the google kickstart round b 2020 first question. but I a facing a RE- Runtime error. can anyone help me to tell? what am I dining wrong?

**Question Problem**

Li has planned a bike tour through the mountains of Switzerland. His tour consists of N checkpoints, numbered from 1 to N in the order he will visit them. The i-th checkpoint has a height of Hi.

**A checkpoint is a peak if:**

It is not the 1st checkpoint or the N-th checkpoint, and
The height of the checkpoint is strictly greater than the checkpoint immediately before it and the checkpoint immediately after it.

Please help Li find out the number of peaks.

**Input**

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a line containing the integer N. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Hi.

**Output**

For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the number of peaks in Li's bike tour.

Limits
Time limit: 10 seconds per test set.
Memory limit: 1GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
1 ≤ Hi ≤ 100.

Test set 1
3 ≤ N ≤ 5.

Test set 2
3 ≤ N ≤ 100.

**Sample**

**Input**

**Output**

```
4
3
10 20 14
4
7 7 7 7
5
10 90 20 90 10
3
10 3 10
```

Case #1: 1
Case #2: 0
Case #3: 2
Case #4: 0

In sample case #1, the 2nd checkpoint is a peak.
In sample case #2, there are no peaks.
In sample case #3, the 2nd and 4th checkpoint are peaks.
In the sample case #4, there are no peaks.

**my Code for that question**

```
for z in range(int(input())):
    no_range,s = input(),list(map(int,input().split()))
    if s[0] and s[-1] < max(s[1:-1]):
        print(f'Case #{z+1}:',s.count(max(s[1:-1])))
    else:print(f'Case #{z+1}:',0)
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Wrong if-conditional:

> ```
> if s[0] and s[-1] < max(s[1:-1]):
> ```

is `True` as soon as `s[0]` is different from `0`. See [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value) :

You could fix the comparison to be

```
if s[0] < max(s[1:-1]) and s[-1] < max(s[1:-1]):
```

but that makes no sense in respect to what your task it: you do not have to check if the first and last number is less then the maximal height of the numbers in between.

### 2. Wrong logic:

Given data of

```
20, 10, 15, 10, 50, 70
```

your code reports the correct number - but the wrong thing - the peak that counts is 10,**15**,10. The **50** (the max value of [1:-1] ) is not a peak!

### 3. Wrong counting:

Furthermore you do not check triplets in with `s.count(max(s[1:-1])))` but you count how often the max value is inside your list.

### Fix:

```
for z in range(int(input())):
    _, s = input(), list(map(int,input().split())) 

    # create triplets of values - this will automagically get rid of the cornercases
    r = zip(s, s[1:], s[2:]) 

    # count how often the middle value is greater then the other 2 values
    print(f'Case #{z+1}: {sum(a<b>c for a,b,c in r)}')
```

Comment: @BB what RE error? Edit your question and add the exact error and stacktrace you get.

Comment: s[1:-1] gives me 2 to last -1 not last -2.

Comment: as you mention:your code reports the correct number - but the wrong thing - the peak that counts is 10,15,10. The 50 (the max value of [1:-1] ) is not a peak!

but s[1:-1] give me - 10, 15, 10, 50

Comment: @BB you need to look at triplets and report any peak thats stricly higher then the one directly before/after.  in `20, 10, 15, 10, 50, 70`. for   `50`: it is not higher then `70` after it so it is not a peak. `15` is because its bigger as the 10's before and after.